# How does this memory leak happen in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have an small application receives data from thousands for agents and upload those data to another server, the data from agents are pretty small, usually 10KB but agents write speed is very fast, so my application has an internal 4M buffer, once buffer is full, it creates a new 4M buffer, and pass the old buffer to a Task to perform HTTP upload. code like this:

```
lock (Locker)
{
    if (input.Length > this.buffer.Length - this.bufferDataLen)
    {
        // Save the current buffer and create a new one. 
        // We should release locker as fast as we can.

        byte[] tempBuffer = this.buffer;
        int oldBufferDataLen = this.bufferDataLen;
        this.buffer = new byte[tempBuffer.Length]; // save size buffer, 4MB
        this.bufferDataLen = 0;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this._uploadUrl);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = this._contentType;
                request.ContentLength = oldBufferDataLen;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Proxy = null;

                UploaderState state = new UploaderState(tempBuffer, oldBufferDataLen, request);
                IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetRequestStream(this.OnGetRequestStreamComplete, state);
                ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, this.TimeoutCallback, state, this._timeoutMs, true);
            });
}

// Copy incoming data to either old buffer or new buffer 
Buffer.BlockCopy(input.Buffer, 0, this.buffer, this.bufferDataLen, input.Length);
this.bufferDataLen += input.Length;
```

}

I expect that tempBuffer will be disposed correctly by GC. However, when I ran my application, I noticed that the memory usage of application increased very fast, from the memory dump, there are 305 byte[] object on managed heap, total size is 469,339,928 B, inclusive size is 469,339,928 B, and that dump is captured when the application ran only few minutes.

My question is why GC didn't free those byte[]? Should I explicitly call GC.Collect? In my case should I manage a buffer pool myself?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the point is that there occurs a closure, when you use a lambda expressions. Sorry if I wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you mean KB and not bytes? 469 gigs seems like a lot of memory... With that in mind, the GC may not start collecting until there is "enough" memory pressure, and 500MB may not be enough to cause that.

Comment: LOH objects are not compacted... So unless Gen2 GC is triggered your buffers will stay in memory. (This is assuming you don't have any references to them which should be easy to check from dump).

Comment: @mbrig sorry my mistake, you are right, it is Byte note KB. 469MB.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov From dump I can see that _ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback has strong handle to those byte[] instances. Might it because I encapsulated byte[] into UploaderState and that is also used in Timeout callback?

Comment: Quite possible. Code sample is somewhat insane mix of creating new threads and legacy asynchronous operations so it would require one non-trivial amount of time to understand what is going on - definitely more than I'm interested to spend on finding answer. I'd recommend to rewrite code to be simpler first (i.e. just legacy async or just threads or simply `async`/`await`) and than try to understand where strong references are coming from.